# Round UIImages in UITableView causes slowdown

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage

When I try to round the UIImages in all custom UITableViewCells, the scrolling of the UITableView is significant slower and not fluid. Is there any better way to to this?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.profileLabel.text = [[demoArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"name"];
 cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[demoArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"image"]];
    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 9.0;
    cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;    
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

While adjusting layer's corner radius is certainly convenient, it may suffer some performance penalty. Personally I would do this very straightforward way.

Create an overlay in any graphics editor — fill the corners so that they match the desired shape, using the same color as cell's background. Now add a new `UIImageView` to your cell, position it directly over your images and make sure an overlay stays on top.

Comment: I can't do this, because the cells have different heights and also an UIImage (with an gradient) as cell background.

Answer (score 0):

1) You could create the rounded images in viewDidLoad (or when your data is ready) and save them into an temporary array. To do that you just create it, as you do it now. Then you capture the view contents into a new image. Afterwards, you show the newly created image in the tableview without dynamic masking.

To save the viewcontents into an image, you can use this code:

```
- (UIImage*) screenshotOfView: (UIView*) view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return viewImage;
}
```

OK, i will be more concrete. In the moment, where your `demoArray` is filled with data. You iterate over that array and pre-render your images. Thats how you do it (using the mentioned method):

```
for(NSDictionary* dictionary in demoArray)
{
    UIImage* originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[dictionary objectForKey:@"image"]];

    UIImageView* tmpImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: originalImage];
    tmpImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 9.0;
    tmpImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    UIImage* roundedImage = [self screenshotOfView: tmpImageView];
    [dictionary setObject: roundedImage forKey: @"roundedImage"];
}
```

Afterwards in your `cellForTableRow` method, you just use that image:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[demoArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"roundedImage"]];
```

(This code is not tested, just wrote it down…)

2) Another probably faster solution would be to draw the images in your tableViewCell subclass within `drawRect:` (masked via CoreGraphics), but that's way more complicated.

3) Following Bartosz Ciechanowski's answer, you could create the needed overlayImage dynamically for each size, that you get using CorGraphics. But the first solution might be the easiest.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. The images in my app will be downloaded from the web and saved in the demoArray. Which view contents should I capture?